iOS on Flutter with Awesome Notifications: Custom Sound Not Playing
I am using the Awesome Notifications package in Flutter to handle notifications across both Android and iOS. While I can successfully implement custom notification sounds on Android, I am facing issues with iOS where no sound is played when a notification is received. If I remove the soundSource parameter, the default notification sound plays without any issues.
Here's the NotificationChannel configuration I am using:
NotificationChannel(
  channelKey: notif.notificationIdIlacZamani_key(),
  channelName: notif.notificationIdIlacZamani_kanal_adi(),
  channelDescription: notif.notificationIdIlacZamani_kanal_aciklama(),
  playSound: true,
  //soundSource: 'resource://raw/tunnel', //for android 
  soundSource: 'tunnel.caf', //for ios
  onlyAlertOnce: true,
  groupAlertBehavior: GroupAlertBehavior.Children,
  importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
  defaultPrivacy: NotificationPrivacy.Public,
  defaultColor: Colors.deepPurple,
  ledColor: Colors.deepPurple,
)

I have placed the tunnel.caf file in the ios/Runner/Resources folder of my project. If I remove the soundSource parameter, the default notification sound plays on iOS.
I've already tried the following:

Ensuring the sound file format is compatible with iOS (.caf in this
case)
Checking the file path and name for any errors
Testing on a    real    iOS device, not just the simulator
Added tunnel.caf to the iOS project in Xcode under Runner/Resources and Runner/Assets and Runner/

However, the custom sound still doesn't play. What am I missing or doing wrong? How can I get custom notification sounds working on iOS?

Yes. I just replaced the "soundSource: 'tunnel.caf'" line with "soundSource: 'resource://raw/tunnel'". Then he started working.

Thanks, there is one issue if i use custom sound path inside createNotification then default sound is playing only in Android.

Did you import sounds into xcode?

Already import in xcode and it's working well, but there is issue in android in createNotification after importing file in drawable, raw.
